# Is there any limit to the number of cards I can have on a board on Trello?

Tags: trello

Basically, I have a big project that involves 150+ individual stores. I will have a set checklist for each store and be moving the stores through various stages in my project.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Chrome, you might use [this add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oekefjibcnongmmmmkdiofgeppfkmdii?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) (Kanban WIP for Trello via the Chrome Web Store) to limit the number of cards. 
It doesn't block cards from being added when you go over the defined maximum, but it colors the cards.

A work-in-progress limit can be added to a Trello list by adding the limit to the list title in braces. If you name your list `QA [5]`, this sets a work-in-progress limit of 5 items to the QA list. When the number of cards in the QA list exceeds 5, the list will be highlighted in red.

Answer (score 2):

There is no technical limit to the number of cards you can have on a board, but there is a practical limit. You might want to adjust your process and break it down into multiple boards. You can easily move cards between boards using the "Move..." button on the back of cards.

Comment: Is there somewhere in the Trello documentation that confirms this? I couldn't find it anywhere in help, though I just tried it out quick and was able to add over 250 cards to a board. (the only limit I saw: can only 100 cards at a time)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Trello for my project QAonAir, as far I know there is no limit for board and card. You can create as many boards and cards as you can.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/limits/

> Trello limits the number of objects (cards, checklists, stickers,
> etc.) that can exist on a board or card. The limits for each type of
> object and whether they are limited at the card or board level are
> available via the cards and boards API resources.

The sample response they include indicates a limit of **4750** cards, but:

> **Your Limits May Vary**
> The responses below and the limits they contain
> are not meant to be the documented limits - they are only examples of
> the type and shape of response you can expect to receive back.
>
> Limits may vary by boards and accounts. You should adjust your
> application to handle the responses and their values appropriately.